# PYTHON в коде в "resultat" отображаются цифры 12, 5, 6, а должны 12, 35, 13

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import math
import time
import os

import my_module as my

my.printSome(my.some)
res = my.summ(5, 8, 12, 10)
print(res)
print(my.summ(6, 3, 4))
```

*файл который импортировали ниже*

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("hi")

some = 12

def printSome(str):
    print("resultat:", str)

def summ(*args):
    summa = 0
    for i in args:
        summa += i

        return summa
```

Answer (score 0):

В функции `summ` напортачили с отступами, из-за чего переменная `summa` возвращается сразу после прибавления к нему первого из аргументов, а не завершения цикла:

```py
def summ(*args):
    summa = 0
    for i in args:
        summa += i

        return summa # вот здесь
    ^^^^
```

Просто уберите лишний отступ у выделенной строки, и функция будет работать нормально. :)